# Samsung Note shutting off

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-note

I just purchased a Samsung Galaxy Note last night so I do not know much about the phone.
When handling and not charging it shuts off on me. It has charged and there is battery life of 70 lets say. When I try to turn it on my battery has completely ran out. Wont even turn on unless it is on the charger. I ordered a new battery but now I am not so sure that is my problem.
As you can imagine I am not a happy customer at this point and will more than likely not be buying from other people any longer.  Any help would be just peachy.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you saying you bought a used phone from another person (not a store) like from ebay or craigslist?

If so, it could very likely be a worn out battery. If the phone was advertised as problem free and fully working, and especially if it was advertised as brand new when clearly not,  you can pursue a return through whatever site you bought it from.

Comment: Unfortuently I was in need of a phone asap and wasn't as cautious as I should have been. I have a feeling it is the battery. I am going to order one so we shall see. I appreciate your comment!!